# Send text in email depends on status of checkbox in WCF7

Tags: checkbox, contact-form-7, status

I have a checkbox field in WCF7

```
[checkbox Newsletteranmeldung use_label_element "YES"]
```

If I send the form an e-mail is send with the Text "Yes", if the form was checked. If the checkbox was empty when sending the form, there ist no text (it's empty). But I want to get a "NO" as output.
How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a toggle button which changes its value each time you click on it.

Place a

```html
<button id="toggle-confirm"> Confirm ? </button>
```

element in your form along with a [hidden field](https://contactform7.com/hidden-field/) to store the toggled value,

```
[hidden confirm "no"] //default no
```

a jquery script to toggle the value each time the button is clicked:

```js
$('button#toggle-confirm').on('change',(e)=>{
 let $hid = $('input[name="confirm"]'),
     $button = $(e.target);
 switch($hid.value()){
   case 'no':
     $hid.value('yes');
     $button.text('Confirmed');
     break;
   case 'yes':
     $hid.value('no');
     $button.text('Confirm?');
     break;
  }
});
```

Use the hidden `confirm` mail tag in your email notification